# Which node in HDFS to request data?

Tags: hdfs

I am building a HDFS cluster and i want to request data. Do I have to send all requests to the master node or Can I do it through any node ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DFS Requests (to read/write data) are made by Hadoop Clients to the Namenode.

> Can I do it through any node?

Any node that has

1. Hadoop installed with the configurations and libraries required to connect with Hadoop Filesystem.
2. User Privileges to access the Filesystem
3. Network access to the Cluster

can be used to make DFS requests.

Obviously, the nodes in the Cluster would qualify as Hadoop Clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use any node in the cluster , and also on any "edge" or "gateway" nodes, which are client nodes with the hadoop libraries and configuration files,and you don't specify a node to which you make the request, but the cluster, internally your request will be sent to the namenode ,and the namenode will send back not the data, but the location of the data and your client node will go to that location to retrieve the data.